# Cannot display Image from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am using smarty, mysql and I am just trying to display image.
This is the error i am getting -

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

#### My index.php file

```
<img src="http://localhost/admin/image2.php?id={$editWine[0].id}" width="150" height="260" border="0" class="bottle-img" id="smallImageWineEdit" />
```

#### My image2.php file

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];        
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id";        
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image_data'] ).'" width="150" height="150" /> &nbsp';  
   echo $row['image_data'];                     
}
```

This echo inside while loop is working fine.

And when i inspect element and open this img link in new tab, Image is displaying. whereas its not displaying in current page.

Comment: Why do you double `<img>` tags in index.php and as output of image2.php? `<img>` tag from index.php expects content-type to be image, but you are sending back from image2.php html code with list of `<img>` tags with data-uris and not content-type image and image's binary code.

Comment: @Cheery. I was just checking whether image is displaying or not thats it.

Comment: So, it not displaying because you are not sending image back to browser.

Comment: I am calling my image2.php in index.php's <img> tag using id..

Comment: you do not understand how http requests are working. look at the answer provided below.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. its working fine now.. i had issues with header type as well as sending proper id.. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that you are again delivering the html tags from the image file. You just need to output the image data with proper image content-type.

Edit `image2.php` like

```
if($row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   header('Content-type: image/jpg');
   echo $row['image_data'];
   exit();                   
}
```

#### update to comments below

Do the above changes and request `http://localhost/admin/image2.php?id=VALID_ID_HERE` in browser and check if its retuning an image. Then you can use it in the src tag of `index.php` to show it there. If you get errors in rendering the image, whn you request it, make sure you are asking for the correct image id in the db and update the question with the error messages you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks.. i tried.. but i wanted to display my image in index.php.

Comment: `image.php`? there are only `image2.php` and `index.php` in your question? which file you are refering to?